# How to take advantage of testosterone and HGH boost provided by leg day?

Tags: bodybuilding, legs, hypertrophy, programs, testosterone

According to Norwegian study, leg exercises, especially squat, result in increased testosterone and human growth hormone (HGH) levels, which in turn resulted in greater biceps growth when biceps were worked immediatly after legs. So, would it make sense to program leg days right before upper body days to take advantage of this hormone boost when working upper body muscles, to maximize hypertrophy?

I think the key question here is how long does this temporary hormone boost last? I was not able to find information about that, but if you have some knowledge on this subject please share your thoughts. Thanks.

Source:
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21327794/

Article on the topic: https://www.gq.com/story/want-bigger-arms-then-keep-doing-squats

Answer (score 1):

It is well-established that intense physical activity, as well as resistance coaching exercises like squats, will result in temporary will increase in androgenic hormone and human STH (HGH) levels. These hormones will play a job in muscle growth and recovery, and should probably contribute to inflated muscle hypertrophy once combined with correct nutrition and coaching.

While it is sensible to contemplate incorporating leg exercises into your exercising routine for the potential edges to muscle growth and overall condition, it's not essentially necessary to program leg days now before higher body days so as to require advantage of any temporary endocrine boosts.

In fact, the most effective approach to maximising muscle hypertrophy might rely on numerous factors like your individual coaching goals, current fitness level, and overall educational program. it's usually suggested to vary your workouts and incorporate a spread of exercises for various muscle teams so as to attain best muscle development and overall condition.

It is conjointly price noting that the length of the temporary endocrine boosts when exercise might vary betting on the intensity and length of the exercising, furthermore as individual factors like age, diet, and biology. it's usually believed that androgenic hormone and HGH levels come back to baseline at intervals many hours to many days when exercise.

It is forever an honest plan to seek {advice from|visit|refer to|talk over with|sit down with} a {professional|a certified} fitness professional or medical supplier for customized advice on the way to style a good exercising program that meets your individual wants and goals.